# Why total derivative becomes partial when we use the differential form of continuity equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, continuum-mechanics

The integral form: $\frac{d q}{d t}+\oint_{S} \vec{j} \cdot d \vec{S}=0$

The differential form: ${\frac {\partial \rho }{\partial t}}+\nabla \cdot \vec{j} =0$

How to intuitively understand the change from total derivative to partial?

Comment: Welcome to PSE! I have removed your second question because there should only be 1 question per post. You are more than welcome to make a new post asking that question though :)

Answer (score 2):

In answer to first question:

The quantity $q$ is the total charge of the system, so it’s not going to vary across space (because it’s the sum charge), so it can only vary across time.

However, the quantity $\rho$ is a charge *density*. The distribution of charge can vary across space (some areas have more charge/volume than others). It can also vary across time. Because it has multiple parameters, we have to take a partial derivative.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, good one!

Comment: I think maybe I should make a separate post on the second question. I will wait for days for good answers here, if not make it I will make a new post.

Comment: I think that’d be a good idea.